# Combining multiple regex substitutions

Tags: python, regex

I'm trying to delete some things from a block of text using regex. I have all of my patterns ready, but I can't seem to be able to remove two (or more) that overlap.

For example:

```
import re

r1 = r'I am'
r2 = r'am foo'

text = 'I am foo'

re.sub(r1, '', text)   # Returns ' foo'
re.sub(r2, '', text)   # Returns 'I '
```

How do I replace both of the occurrences simultaneously and end up with an empty string?

---

I ended up using a slightly modified version of [Ned Batchelder's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11442587/464744):

```
def clean(self, text):
  mask = bytearray(len(text))

  for pattern in patterns:
    for match in re.finditer(pattern, text):
      r = range(match.start(), match.end())

      mask[r] = 'x' * len(r)

  return ''.join(character for character, bit in zip(text, mask) if not bit)
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can't do it with consecutive `re.sub` calls as you have shown.  You can use `re.finditer` to find them all.  Each match will provide you with a match object, which has `.start` and `.end` attributes indicating their positions.  You can collect all those together, and then remove characters at the end.

Here I use a `bytearray` as a mutable string, used as a mask.  It's initialized to zero bytes, and I mark with an 'x' all the bytes that match any regex.  Then I use the bit mask to select the characters to keep in the original string, and build a new string with only the unmatched characters:

```
bits = bytearray(len(text))
for pat in patterns:
    for m in re.finditer(pat, text):
        bits[m.start():m.end()] = 'x' * (m.end()-m.start())
new_string = ''.join(c for c,bit in zip(text, bits) if not bit)
```

Comment: I never thought about the `start` and `end` attributes for the match objects. I'm more than sure that this will work, so thanks!

Comment: Great answer! I added `()` to `start` and `end`, because these are methods, not attributes.

Answer (score 2):

Not to be a downer, but the short answer is that I'm pretty sure **you can't.** Can you change your regex so that it doesn't require overlapping?

If you still want to do this, I would try keeping track of the **start and stop indices** of each match made on the original string. Then go through the string and only keep characters not in any deletion range?

Answer (score 1):

Quite efficient too is a solution coming from ... Perl combine the regexps in one:

```
# aptitude install regexp-assemble
$ regexp-assemble 
I am
I am foo
Ctrl + D
I am(?: foo)?
```

regexp-assemble takes all the variants of regexps or string you want to match and then 
combine them in one. And yes it changes the initial problem to another one since it is not about matching overlapping regexp anymore, but combining regexp for a match

And Then you can use it in your code:

```
$ python
Python 2.7.3 (default, Aug  1 2012, 05:14:39) 
[GCC 4.6.3] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import re
>>> re.sub("I am foo","I am(?: foo)?","")
''
```

A port of Regexp::Assemble in python would be nice :)

Comment: The command is `aptitude install libregexp-assemble-perl`.  I couldn't quickly find any trace of a previous package with the name you indicate, but maybe you are on a different distro; this is for Debian stable.

Comment: Also, in older versions of the package, the demo was only in `/usr/share/doc/libregexp-assemble-perl/examples/assemble.gz` -- I wanted this on a `squeeze` box, where the script is not installed with the name you indicate.

Answer (score 1):

Here is an alternative that filters the strings on the fly using `itertools.compress` on the text with a selector iterator. The selector returns `True` if the character should be kept. `selector_for_patterns` creates one selector for every pattern. The selector are combined with the all function (only when all pattern want to keep a character it should be in the resulting string).

```
import itertools
import re

def selector_for_pattern(text, pattern):
    i = 0
    for m in re.finditer(pattern, text):
        for _ in xrange(i, m.start()):
            yield True
        for _ in xrange(m.start(), m.end()):
            yield False
        i = m.end()
    for _ in xrange(i, len(text)):
        yield True

def clean(text, patterns):
    gen = [selector_for_pattern(text, pattern) for pattern in patterns]
    selector = itertools.imap(all, itertools.izip(* gen))
    return "".join(itertools.compress(text, selector))
```